# Press a specific button of external application without a name whit hexadecimal handle

Tags: vb.net, button, handle

In an external application, there are 8 buttons with any text and all with the same class.
How can i get the exact button that i want?

With FindWindowEx, is it possible to insert an hexadecimal value (taken from spy++) instead of a string?

```
Dim h1 = FindWindow(Nothing, "TitleWindow")
Dim h2 = FindWindowEx(h1, Nothing, Nothing, "TextButton")
SendMessage(h2, BM_CLICK, 0, 0)
```

[image: Here are the buttons]

Comment: If this is one app and you have a button named 'TextButton' then the handle is TextButton.Handle.

Comment: What platform is this? Windows Forms, Asp.net? Wpf?

Comment: You can find the name of your button in design view by selecting the control and then looking at the Properties window. You can refer to the control in code by the Name property.

Comment: To get an event handler, in design view double click on the control. A stub will appear in the code window for the default Event.

Comment: If you want to run code in an event handler from somewhere else, move the code to a separate method and call it from the event handler and the other place.

Comment: @Mary The image and the use of FindWindow API suggests that the OP is trying to click a button on a running app that isn't theirs.

Comment: @LarsTech Sorry, I went down the wrong path. I got caught on "In my application, there are 8 buttons" I assumed the buttons were in his code.

Comment: @Mary Maybe you're right.  Would help if the user explained themselves a bit better.

Comment: I need to press the button in an external application

Comment: If you already have the handle then why call `FindWindow` and `FindWindowEx` at all? The whole point of those functions is to get a handle. If you already have a handle, just call `SendMessage` and pass that handle. That said, the handle will be different every time the app runs because it is assigned by the OS at run time, so I doubt that that's possible.

Comment: What you should be doing is using Spy++ to determine the structure of that app, i.e. where in the series of 8 buttons the one you want is located. That tells you how many times you need to call `FindWindowEx` to get that handle. After the first time, you pass the handle from the previous call as the sibling.

Comment: I can't insert the button on `FindWindowEx` becouse the button haven't a text. How can i insert the hexadecimal value of spy++ on `FindWindowEx`?